# Select Deployment Target Window

Tags: android, android-studio

My Select Deployment Target window isn't showing when I hit Run. It is only showing the signing report in the Run tab on the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

On the Taskbar,click on

**RUN>EDIT CONFIGURATION>TARGET**

And set the target as per your wish.
Worked for me.
Hope the same for you too.

Answer (score 3):

If the Select Deployment Target window isn't showing when you hit Run. Make sure the dropdown (next to Run button) is set to "App".

It took me a while to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the very lower-right corner of Android Studio. If the "!" in a circle is lit up red, click on it. There may be an error you have to dispose of before you click run.